# Is it possible to put list in a table or make a set in R?

Tags: r

I am using R to align the relationships between almost 40,000 items.
There are two types of relationships 0, -1.
To give a simple example, the data is in the form like

```
a|b|0
a|c|1
a|d|0
b|a|0
b|c|0
b|d|1
```

and I wish to align them in the form of

```
a{
  0: b,d
  1: c
},
b{
  0: a,c
  1: d
}
```

to make it easier to search and see the relation between items.
I'm not sure even it is possible, but I would really love a help from R experts.

Comment: `Group|transform|aggregate tabular data[frame] into nested map|dictionary with ordered keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe

```
df=read.table(text="
a|b|0
a|c|1
a|d|0
b|a|0
b|c|0
b|d|1",h=F,sep="|")
```

then

```
lapply(
  split(df,df$V1),
  function(x){
    split(x$V2,x$V3)
  }
)

$a
$a$`0`
[1] "b" "d"

$a$`1`
[1] "c"

$b
$b$`0`
[1] "a" "c"

$b$`1`
[1] "d"
```

it's not a dictionary but a list.